# can not use "[" symbol in awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I can not use "[" symbol in awk command. Please see below

```
awk -F 'CDATA[|PSCRI' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< ${y[0]}
```

**Throws:**

```
awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /CDATA[|PSCRI/
```

I have also tried "\" to skip, its not working

```
awk -F 'CDATA\[|PSCRI' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< ${y[0]}
```

**Throws:**

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /CDATA[|PSCRI/
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
awk -F 'CDATA\\[|PSCRI' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< ${y[0]}
```

example:

```
kent$ (master|✔) echo "bbb[fooaaa"|awk -F '\\[foo' '$1=$1'
bbb aaa
```

Comment: if i try this it is throwing error. `awk -F"<\\!\\[CDATA" '{print $0}'` throwing 
`awk: warning: escape sequence \!' treated as plain !'
awk: warning: escape sequence \[' treated as plain ['`
`

Comment: @logan, you see in my anwser, I used `-F '..'` single quote. if you love double quote, use in this way: `-F "\\\\[foo"`